# how to merge the similar file name together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can merge the similar file's name together?
for example, I have

```
{"Apple USA": 25$, "Apple Japan": 26$, "Avocado Mexico":30$, "Avocado Brazil":35$}
```

then I want to know the total amount of cost of Apple and Avocado. how should I do that in Python?

And I want to have a table that shows

```
{"Apple":51$,"Avocado":65$}
```

Thank you!

Comment: does your data is like that way ? i mean is it in dict format ?If not then can you provide some data something like df.head() in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate the dict assumning that is a dict as you showed us...

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = {"Apple USA": 25, "Apple Japan": 26, "Avocado Mexico":30, "Avocado Brazil":35} 
dic = defaultdict(lambda: int(0))
for key,val in data.items():
    name,*_ = key.split()
    dic[name] = dic[name] + val
```

Output:

```
>>>dict(dic)

 {'Apple': 51, 'Avocado': 65}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [iterate over the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) and use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to separate the key into pieces.